# Minecraft Spigot/Bukkit plugin throws NullPointerException on equality check

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I'm trying to create a menu, and I want to make sure all players have the compass on join.

My code does not work- if you have a no-named compass in your inventory, it just doesn't give you a compass. If I don't check for those `== null`, my code gives a `NullPointerException` with the above described conditions.

Eclipse displays no errors. What am I doing wrong?

```java
package me.psrcek.compassMenu.listeners;

import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerJoinEvent;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;
import org.bukkit.inventory.meta.ItemMeta;

public class PlayerJoinListener implements Listener {

    @EventHandler
    public void onJoin(PlayerJoinEvent e) {
        ItemStack[] inv = e.getPlayer().getInventory().getContents();
        
        for (ItemStack item : inv) {
            if (item == null) continue;
            
            if (item.getType().equals(Material.COMPASS)) {
                if (item.getItemMeta().getDisplayName() == null) continue;
                
                if (item.getItemMeta().getDisplayName().equals(ChatColor.RESET + "" + ChatColor.AQUA + "Menu")) {
                    e.getPlayer().sendMessage("found proppertly named compass");
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        
        ItemStack compass = new ItemStack(Material.COMPASS);
        ItemMeta compassMeta = compass.getItemMeta();
        
        compassMeta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.RESET + "" + ChatColor.AQUA + "Menu");
        
        compass.setItemMeta(compassMeta);
        
        e.getPlayer().getInventory().addItem(compass);
        e.getPlayer().updateInventory();

    }

}
```

Comment: Have you checked the bukkit/spigot forms for answers?

Comment: @Oisin found nothing about this on there, thats why i asked here.

Comment: Could you please post the stack trace for the NPE that was thrown? `item.getItemMeta()` will, as far as I know, only possibly return `null` for air blocks, but since you're only getting the metadata for compass items, that will never be the case. Since you're already checking whether the item is null and whether the display name exists, I don't see where your code could possibly have a `null` reference.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why this worked, but changing

```
item.getType().equals(Material.COMPASS)
```

to

```
item.getType() == Material.COMPASS
```

made it work. I always thought those were the same thing.

Comment: Yes, they are essentially the same thing, the default implementation of the `equals` method for enumerators is `public final boolean equals(Object other) {return this == other}`, so changing between `equals` and `==` should make no difference, you probably changed something else in your code.

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple places from which a NullPointerException could come. 
First, you are checking in the item is null, and if it is, checking if it is a compass. But if it's null, it can't also be a compass. Try this instead:

```
if(item != null){
    if(item.getType() == Material.COMPASS){

    }
}
```

The second spot I saw right away is in that same for loop, when you get the compass's item meta. Well Bukkit doesn't like to say that an itemStack has an itemMeta until you assign it one, so try this instead:

```
if(item.getType() == Material.COMPASS){
    if(item.hasItemMeta()){
        if(item.getItemMeta().getDisplayName().contains(ChatColor.AQUA + "Menu"){
            p.sendMessage("found properly named compass");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

If you want a much simpler way to go about this though, I would recommend using the following example code:

```
ItemStack compass = new ItemStack(Material.COMPASS);
ItemMeta compassMeta = compass.getItemMeta();

//No need to use ChatColor.RESET before the text has a color
compassMeta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.AQUA + "Menu");

compass.setItemMeta(compassMeta);

for(ItemStack item:e.getPlayer().getInventory().getContents()){
    if(item != null){
        if(item.equals(compass)){
            p.sendMessage("found properly named compass");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this was helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

The `.equals` method and the `==` operator are not the same thing.

`.equals` compares the values of the objects.

`==` compares the reference (location in memory) of the objects.

Example:

```java
Integer x = 10;
Integer y = 10;

// is false
System.out.println(x == y)

// is true
System.out.println(x.equals(y))
```

Comment: Due to the rules of boxing for small integers, `x == y` will return `true` in your case, since both `Integer` wrapper classes are referencing the same primitive value. If `x` and/or `y` had been instantiated with `new Integer(10)`, the comparison with `==` would've returned false, as well as if the primitive values had been larger. This specific question also refers to enumerators, where using the `==` operator for comparison is valid.